# Copy color from one shape to another in PowerPoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have tried this:

```
var background_color = presentation.Slides[1].Shapes[1].Fill.BackColor.RGB;

presentation.Slides[1].Shapes[2].Fill.BackColor.RGB = background_color;
```

but it doesn't set the color. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: please read http://www.sscce.org

Comment: Use .Fill.ForeColor.RGB instead of .Fill.BackColor.RGB